# WPF-application out of memory when deployed on Win7 x64

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, out-of-memory, windows-7-x64

Does anyone know what will cause the following exception on a WPF application?  Started happening after deployment on Windows 7 x64.   Application is using .NET 3.5 and there is no specific action that causes this and length of time application has been running is random.

```
Message : Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
Source : PresentationCore
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Boolean CreateOrAddRefOnChannel(ResourceHandle ByRef, ResourceType)
Stack Trace :    at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.CreateOrAddRefOnChannel(ResourceHandle& handle, ResourceType resourceType)
   at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.MultiChannelResource.CreateOrAddRefOnChannel(Channel channel, ResourceType type)
   at System.Windows.Media.RenderData.System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.IResource.AddRefOnChannel(Channel channel)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RenderContent(RenderContext ctx, Boolean isOnChannel)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateContent(RenderContext ctx, VisualProxyFlags flags, Boolean isOnChannel)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx, ResourceHandle handle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.Render(RenderContext ctx, UInt32 childIndex)
   at System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.Compile(Channel channel)
   at System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget.Render(Boolean inResize, Channel channel)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Render(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop, which happens to be running out of memory/resources before a stack overflow is occurring.

Comment: The error is generated by native code, Milcore, a wrapper for DirectX.  It is a pretty generic error code, E_OUTOFMEMORY, it tends to be used by native code for more than one reason.  What ever resources your program is using, it ran out of them.  That's all that's clear.

Comment: @Hans, yes it is clear application is running out of resources.  This same application when run on a 32bit version of windows never runs out of resources.  It is a complex application that utilizes a lot of resources so I am guessing that by compiling forcing it to run as a 32 bit process under WOW64 introduces some of these problems.  Especially considering the memory and performance overhead imposed by WOW64.  I am now compiling the application using Any CPU to see how it performs.  I suspect we will not see these problems.

Answer (score 2):

I've found at least 1 cause of this issue. If the DataGrid is placed into a container like a StackPanel which allows the child control to resize infinitely, then you get an OutOfMemoryException when you bind a large list (for me 17k rows).

If you place the DataGrid in a fixed height container like a Grid, then it works fine.

Ironically I discovered this by trialing the DevExpress WPF library. Their grid actually throws an exception with the following text in this instance.

*A first chance exception of type 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.InfiniteGridSizeException' occurred in DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v13.2.Core.dll
Additional information: By default, an infinite grid height is not allowed since all grid rows will be rendered and hence the grid will work very slowly. To fix this issue, you should place the grid into a container that will give a finite height to the grid, or you should manually specify the grid's Height or MaxHeight. Note that you can also avoid this exception by setting the GridControl.AllowInfiniteGridSize static property to True, but in that case the grid will run slowly.*

Once I saw this the penny dropped and I could then replicate and then fix the original behaviour with the Microsoft DataGrid.